# Typescript class with private

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

in a js file, I have built a library of common functions I may need on various pages.  I've organized the functions by simulating a namespacing scheme, and I've also used a pattern to hide, as best as I can, private properties and functions that I don't want to expose for direct use.

Here is the pattern

```
var mynamespace = (function () {

    var private = {
        funcX: function (): any {..},
    };

    var public =
        {
            subnamespace1: {
                func1: function (ctl: HTMLElement): boolean {...},
            },

            subnamespace2: {

                func2: function (sender: any, args: any): void {...},

                func3: function (sender: any, args: any): void {
                    private.funcx();
                },
            }
        };

    return public;

})();
```

As long as the page includes the js, I can then execute any of the functions with in the library easily:

```
mynamespace.subnamespace2.func2(x,y);
```

So far this has worked well, but I'm trying to get into using TypeScript for the first time and I'm looking to implement a similar pattern.  I want the library to be built in typescript, but the pages may only use js, not typescript.

My first attempt was to do this...

```
namespace mynamespace {
    namespace subnamespace1 {
        export function func1(): boolean {...}
    }
    namespace subnamespace2 {
        export function func2(): boolean {...}
        export function func3(): boolean {...}
    }
}
```

...which did not work, because I couldn't access the sub namespace

So I tried this...

```
namespace mynamespace {
    export class subnamespace1 {
        func1(): boolean {...}
    }
    export class subnamespace2 {
        func2(): boolean {...}
        func3(): boolean {...}
    }
}
```

...which did not work, because although I could access the sub namespace, I couldn't access the functions.

Is it possible to build Typescript in such a way that would output js in a similar way that my original javascript pattern follows, or so it accomplishes the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your namespace approach, you just need to export the sub namespaces

```
namespace mynamespace {
  function funcX(): boolean { return false; }
  namespace private {
    export function funcPrivate(): boolean { return false; }
  }

  export namespace subnamespace1 {
    export function func1(): boolean { return funcX(); }
  }
  export namespace subnamespace2 {
    export function func2(): boolean { return private.funcPrivate(); }
    export function func3(): boolean { return true; }
  }
}

mynamespace.subnamespace1.func1(); // ok in both js and ts
mynamespace.subnamespace2.func2(); // ok in both js and ts
mynamespace.funcX() // not accesible
mynamespace.private.funcPrivate() // not accesible
```

The namespace solution will not output exactly the same js as your hand written version (it relies a lot more on function closures) but the functionality should be the same.

If generating the same JS pattern is important to  you, you could just stick with your JS version with TS types added. There should be no reason for it not to work:

```
var mynamespace = (function () {

    var private = {
        funcX: function (): any {},
    };

    var public =
        {
            subnamespace1: {
              func1: function (ctl: HTMLElement): boolean { return true;},
            },

            subnamespace2: {

                func2: function (sender: any, args: any): void { },

                func3: function (sender: any, args: any): void {
                    private.funcX();
                },
            }
        };

    return public;

})();
mynamespace.subnamespace1.func1(null); // ok in both js and ts
mynamespace.subnamespace2.func2(null, null); // ok in both js and ts
```